# Loading countries in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a set of values which are country codes in my ajax call

```
Handler.getCountryIdparam1, {callback:function(data){
    // data will have values like "IN", "AS" 
}
```

For the country codes, I have to give the country name which I may have it in a separate array.

I am confused implementing logic on matching country code and fetching the name of the countries to load those in a dropdown.
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try may be something like this:

```
var  countries = {'IN': 'India' , 'RU' : 'Russia' , 'ES' : 'Spain'};
Handler.getCountryIdparam1, {callback:function(data){

        optString = "";
        lgth = data.length;
        for(i = 0; i < lgth; i++){
            if(typeof countries[data[i]] != 'undefined'){
                optString += '<option value="'+data[i]+'">'+countries[data[i]]+'</option>';
            }
        }
        jQuery('#countryid').html(optString);

}
```

This is untested code. So you might need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its is an empty dropdown where I have to load it based on previous dropdown's value. <select id="countryid" name = countryid" > <option> select </option> thats all.

Comment: @sahana data is a single country string, or an array of countries?

Comment: it will be list of values. data[0] = "IN", data[1] = "AS" etc.

Comment: Thank you. will check and let you know :)

Comment: It works .. thanks a lot :) can you help me to load the same in dropdown? I am facing issues. optString += '<option value="'+data[i]+'">'+countries[data[i]]+'</option>'; where to mention the id of dropdown ?

Comment: @sahana `jQuery('#countryid').html(optString);` line holds the container ID. change #countryid to your desired id.. if it's a class then use . instead of #